# How to select 10 rows for a each column value in the 'IN' statement (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to pull 10 records of data for each listed in the IN statement in T-SQL?

Here is the query example:

```
SELECT 
    student_id, student_name, student_phnumber
FROM 
    student
WHERE 
    student_name IN ('Rachel', 'Adam', 'Terry')
```

I want only 10 people with name Rachel and 10 with Adam and 10 with Terry. In the database, there are 1000's with that name. How do I do this without using union?

This is just an example SQL. The one I am working with it has millions of rows

Comment: Removed mySQL tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way with a window function.

```
with cte as(
   Select student_id
      ,student_name
      ,student_phnumber
      ,row_number() over (partition by student_name order by student_id) rn
from student
where student_name in ( 'Rachel','Adam','Terry'))

select * from cte where rn < 11
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `Apply` operator and `Table valued constructor`

```
SELECT tc.student_name, 
       oa.* 
FROM   (VALUES ('Rachel'),('Adam'),('Terry'))tc (student_name) 
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 10 student_id, 
                                  student_name, 
                                  student_phnumber 
                    FROM   student a 
                    WHERE  a.student_name = tc.student_name) oa
```

creating following `index` will help the query to run faster

```
create nonclustered index nix_student 
           on student (student_name) include (student_id,student_phnumber )
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT student_id, student_name, student_phnumber
FROM (
     SELECT student_id
           ,student_name
           ,student_phnumber
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_name ORDER BY student_name) RN
     FROM student
     WHERE student_name in ( 'Rachel','Adam','Terry')
     ) A
WHERE RN < 11
```

@scsimon Beat me to it.. I'll leave this just to show the inline way of writing it.

Answer (score -1):

`select * from 
(
Select student_id
      ,student_name
      ,student_phnumber
      ,row_number() over (partition by student_name order by student_id) rn
from student
where 
group by student_name 
)
where student name in ( 'Rachel','Adam','Terry'))
and rn <11;`